# MS Word: Using Formulas with Custom Doc Properties

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Anyone know how to add 1 to a custom document property? For some reason this really simple equation escapes me. I have a custom property, Document_Number, saved as a Number format. When revealing field codes, I've tried these lines:

```
{ = { DOCPROPERTY "Document_Number"  \* MERGEFORMAT } + 1 }
{ = { DOCPROPERTY "Document_Number"  \* MERGEFORMAT + 1} }
{ = { DOCPROPERTY "Document_Number" +1 \* MERGEFORMAT } }
```

Books don't seem to cover this. Google doesn't seem to cover this. What am I doing wrong? I just want to add 1 to the document property. This can't be that hard to put together a formula, right?

Comment: Assumed I could do math calculations on user-defined properties if it was a numeric type. Does anyone know a property I can use to show the number of a document in a series of documents that I can add 1 to?

Comment: If you’re trying to *change* the document property, the answer that says “You can’t” is right. But if you’re just trying to *display* the result of a computation involving a document property as a term — your first option (```{ = { DOCPROPERTY "Document_Number"  \* MERGEFORMAT } +1 }```) worked for me (in Word 2013).

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work:

1. Insert field and add your custom doc property:
   `{ DOCPROPERTY "Document_Number"}`
2. Insert a second field as a formula field. Make it a simple one e.g., `{=1+2}`
3. Toggle field codes for both fields
4. Copy the first field, paste it over the "2" within the second field code
5. Update fields

Voilà

Check by editing your custom doc property from with in the properties menu and then do a blanket field update

Answer (score 1):

Example - how to calculate how many minutes in a speech based on the number of words in a document and displaying it the document

Step 1. Insert doc properties "Numwords" in your document e.g Words - 2767

Step 2. Select the result and create a bookmark. "NW" for example

Step 3. Fo to Insert/Field/Formula and use Paste bookmark to insert the bookmark NW

Step 4. Type the formula - for example  "= NW/150" for 150 words per minute

Step 5. Click OK - the value will display in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the value of a Custom Document Property using a field code.

In principle, it might look as if you could do it by making it a linked property, i.e. connected to the value of a bookmark, and update the content of the bookmark. But AFAICS it doesn't actually work.

You can update the value of the AUTHOR, TITLE, SUBJECT, KEYWORDS and COMMENTS *builtin* document properties using a field construction, e.g. for AUTHOR you could use:

```
{ AUTHOR { ={ AUTHOR }+1 } }
```

(If you literally mean that you can't take a Custom Document Property and display "1+its value", you have probably used the {} you can type on the keyboard for at least one of the brace pairs, instead of the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 in Windows Word.)

Comment: I typed in the above formula (subsituting AUTHOR for DOCPROPERTY "Document number") and I used Ctrl+F9 to insert the braces instead of typing them, but no dice. The document number displayed the current number, but no incrementation. But, like was discussed above, I guess you just can't perform math on custom properties, numeric or not. :/